# GQL Reference for Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

Anyone have a good reference guide for GQL (query language for google appengine datastore)?

I find the reference guide on the google appengine site very limited with examples

Comment: I think the [reference guide](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) is actually pretty good.  Do you have a specific query or queries that you'd like to see examples for?

Answer (score 3):

The doc is limited because GQL is a very, very simple query language, intended to provided an SQL-like interface on top of protocol buffers. There's not a lot of complexity to it.

The most instructive thing may be to read the GQL source. It's online [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/gql/__init__.py). Note in particular how GQL is parsed with a simple, hand-rolled top-down parser.